# Why isn't this column being converted into a decimal

Tags: sql-server

I'm asked

[image]

I'm using a cast function to subtract the grosspay from the taxwitholding and making it the netpay. I'm trying to convert it into a decimal but im getting an integer

```
SELECT PerFrom, PerThru, EmpName, CAST(GrossPay AS decimal) AS Gross, CAST(TaxWitholding AS decimal) AS Taxes,
InsCost, (CAST(GrossPay AS decimal) - CAST(TaxWitholding AS decimal) - InsCost) AS NetPay
FROM vwPayCalc
WHERE PerFrom =
    (SELECT MAX(PerFrom)
     FROM vwPayCalc)
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: [`max()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: We don't do homework assignments.

Comment: We do not, except when the person asking the question showed effort though. What is the difference between people at work that showed effort to solve a problem, and a person doing homework showing effort? @SezMe

Comment: @TT  The difference is that at work a person is expected to reach out to pros if they have a problem.  That's considered cheating in school.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the DECIMAL type in `CAST(... AS DECIMAL)` without specifying the precision and scale, defaults to precision=18 and scale=0. In other words, a DECIMAL with zero decimal digits. More information in the documentation on numeric data types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql#arguments).

It is never a good idea to rely on defaults; always specify the precision and scale required. Write something like `CAST(... AS DECIMAL(18,2))` for instance.